# No clock displayed on presented Interface Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I have three InterfaceControllers that I am presenting with the code:

```
    self.presentControllerWithName("new", context: self)
```

For some reason, whereas the InterfaceControllers that are connected to the main Controller (with a segue) display the time in the upper right hand corner, the ones that are presented with the above code do not.

Is this because of the way I am presenting the Controllers, or is there another reason? If so, does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[presentControllerWithName:context:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/presentControllerWithName:context:) will present your WKInterfaceController modally and as per Apple's documentation:

> **Discussion**
>
> After calling this method, WatchKit loads and initializes the new
>   interface controller and animates it into position on top of the
>   current interface controller. A modal interface slides up from the
>   bottom of the screen and **completely cover** the previous interface.

You might instead use [pushControllerWithName:context:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/pushControllerWithName:context:) which will simply push your controller without covering the clock area